# Count Unique Values with CountIF works in Excel but gives type mismatch error in VBA

Tags: vba, excel-formula, countif, type-mismatch, unique-values

So I'm trying to get how many unique categories I have in my data range and I know how to do it in Excel

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(général!N2:N229;général!N2:N229))
```

but when I try to use it via VBA i get a type mismatch error.

```
 WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(1 / Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("N2:N229"), Range("N2:N229")))
```

---

```
x4 = Worksheets("général").Cells(Rows.Count, 14).End(xlUp).Row
```

'x4=229

```
WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(1 / WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("N2:N"& x4), Range("N2:N" & x4)))
```

---

```
 WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(1 / WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("général").Range("N2:N" & x4), Worksheets("général").Range("N2:N" & x4)))
```

---

Can someone help me? It's driven me insane.

Answer (score 1):

In VBA the worksheet functions do not behave exactly in the same way. You can use `Evaluate`, writing the formulas as they are and using range addresses. But a better way would be using a `Scripting.Dictionary`. Please, try the next code, which will return the unique values number, but also which are these unique values and how many per each (in columns "O:P"):

```
Sub countUnique()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, i As Long, dict As Object
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  lastR = sh.Range("N" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
  arr = sh.Range("N2:N" & lastR).value 'place the range in an array for  faster processing
  Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  dict.CompareMode = TextCompare

  For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
    dict(arr(i, 1)) = dict(arr(i, 1)) + 1
  Next i
  
  Debug.Print dict.count & " unique values"
  sh.Range("O2").Resize(dict.count, 1).value = Application.Transpose(dict.Keys)
  sh.Range("P2").Resize(dict.count, 1).value = Application.Transpose(dict.items)
End Sub
```

To `Evaluate` the worksheet function, please try the next piece of code:

```
Sub CountUniqueEvaluate()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, rng As Range
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  lastR = sh.Range("N" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
  Set rng = sh.Range("N2:N" & lastR)
  
   Debug.Print Evaluate("=SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(" & rng.Address & ", " & rng.Address & "))")
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi FaneDure, tks for your answer, here're my thoughts:

I managed to get what I wanted with the following:

unique = WorksheetFunction.unique(Worksheets("général").Range("N2:N" & x4))
a = UBound(unique)

it gives me a total of 7 categories, it's correct

----
as for your code:

Sub countUnique() gives me 9 categories, it differentiates between upper and lower case, but that's my problem, the code works

----
Sub CountUniqueEvaluate() still throws the same mismatch error

----
I now have a follow up question.
Do you know how to filter conditions with the unique function?

Comment: @Alex Silva The case sensitive issue is easy to be solved. I will immediately adapt the code to not be case sensitive. anymore. This should be an advantage, if you want to differentiate according to this aspect...

Comment: @Alex Silva OK, adapted. This code returns each unique value **and its number of occurrences**...

Comment: Hi FaneDuru, sorry for the super late reply, had to urgently change focus to another project. Tested the CountUniqueEvaluate Sub, it's perfect thank you. Is it possible to change the countUnique Sub to also ignore upper and lower cases? I've tried the following, |||||  a = Evaluate("=UNIQUE(" & rng.Address & ", " & rng.Address & "))") |||| but it throws an error, namely "2015 error".
Thank you for all the help and patient and once again sorry for the late reply.

Comment: @Alex I am afraid, I cannot get you... The above code is already adapted to not be case sensitive. I mean "a" and "A" will be counted in the same category. I have the impression that you didn't even test it and need my opinion about the second issue involving `Evaluate`... Did you change the above sub the name in `UNIQUE`? If yes, it should be a function to be called from a cell (UDF). Are you referring to `UNIQUE` Excel function? If so:  Firstly, do you use Excel 365?, Secondly, the `UNIQUE`  function does need only a single parameter. What do you need, in fact?

Comment: I tested it, you can see the result of the test in the following print,  https://prnt.sc/zLwvtvmrE1ix  || As you can see, it returns several instances of "aaaa" while with the unique function on excel only gives 4 results with the "aaaa" string that appears first in the range being the one displayed. || It's not ideal but i managed to get what I wanted with a R1C1 Formula, I just thought you would know a better way. There's no need to be so hostile, tks for everything anyway. || Yes, I use office 365. Yes, I know. I need unique values ignoring upper and lower cases like the print.

Comment: @Alex Silva I am not able to understand too much from the way of making the comparison. For "N2:N5" filled with "aAaa, aaaa, aaaA, aaAa" returns in "O2" "aAaa" (first occurrence) and in "P2" `4`, which means the number of occurrences for **the same key**.  Of course, you should update the range to be processed for these 5 cells. Did you copy the updated code, having a code line `dict.CompareMode = TextCompare`? You maybe did not refresh the page (this one) and uses the old code. If you want using `UNIQUE`  Excel function, like I said, it accepts only one argument.

Comment: @Alex Silva It should be `a = Evaluate("=UNIQUE(" & rng.Address & ")")`, followed by
   `Range("T1").Resize(UBound(a), 1).value = a`, to return the array in the "T:T" column, starting from "T1". Of course, `rng` must be correctly set for the same "N2:N5" range. I still cannot get you... How to get you, if the result you are talking about is not the one returned by my code?

Comment: Yes, I refreshed this page and copied the updated code. I gives the result in the print. The range to be analysed is "N2:N14", with N14 being your lastR variable. I teste the new Evaluate formula, and it's exactly what I needed, I will use that since it's a much more elegant way of getting the data that i want than my R1C1 formula. Thank you for all the help and the time spent on me, much aprecciated.